how you can create a wavy line pattern for a cloth in Adobe Illustrator
Hy I'm very new to illustrator and few days back i stumbled upon an artist who made this illustration

I really want to know how do i achieve similar clothing effect in illustrator

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried using the Warp tool in Illustrator?

If your question is about Illustrator, please don't use the Phothsop tag. Relevant tags help users find questions actually related to any search.

It's not an "easy" task to create the composition. However, configuring the basic set up for the distorted "waves" is rather straightforward.

Draw a series of rectangles
Select the rectangles and choose Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh
Move the mesh points


In terms of the composition you may need to repeat the above several times using a different mesh for each part of any fabric. This is one of those compositions that appears kind of simple at a glance, but really is not.
